# Sending POST with RestKit returns no JSON content

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, rest, restkit

So, i m sending a POST request for the first time. I m Mapping classes and as I thought and read from the Documentation that it would work in this way:

**Init RK:**

```
- (void)initRK{
    if(!manager){
        manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_CONTEXT_URL]];
    }

    if (!reqMapping) {
        reqMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    }
}
```

**POST Method:**

```
// Configure a request mapping for our Article class. We want to send back title, body, and publicationDate
RKObjectMapping* deviceRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[DeviceDTO class]];
[deviceRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"model", @"name", @"systemName", @"systemVersion", @"devToken" ]];

RKObjectMapping* msRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MemberShipDTO class]];
[msRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"validSince", @"validTill" ]];

RKObjectMapping* countryRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CountryDTO class]];
[countryRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"idNumberDTO", @"iso2DTO", @"short_nameDTO", @"calling_codeDTO" ]];

RKObjectMapping* userRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[userRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"displayName", @"phoneNumber", @"status", @"userID" ]];

[userRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"device" withMapping:deviceRequestMapping]];
[userRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"memberShip" withMapping:msRequestMapping]];
[userRequestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"country" withMapping:countryRequestMapping]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userRequestMapping objectClass:[User class] rootKeyPath:@"user"];


//Create Objects
UserDTO *user = [[UserDTO alloc]init];
user.displayName = userDTO.displayName;
user.phoneNumber = userDTO.phoneNumber;
user.status = userDTO.status;
user.userID = userDTO.userID;
user.country = userDTO.country;

DeviceDTO *device = [[DeviceDTO alloc]init];
device.name = devDTO.name;
device.systemName = devDTO.systemName;
device.systemVersion = devDTO.systemVersion;
device.model = devDTO.model;
device.devToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:PUSHTOKEN_USER_DEFAULTS_KEY];

user.deviceInfo = device;

MemberShipDTO *ms = [[MemberShipDTO alloc]init];
ms.validSince = [NSDate date];
ms.validTill = [[UtilitieHandler new] getDateByAdd:+1 :0 :0 :0];

user.memberShipDetails = ms;

[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/json"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user path:@"user/integrate" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
    RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Articles: %@", mappingResult.array);
}failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];
```

So I tried different things and after i used wireshark to capture the request it returns that theres no content send. That means the mapping is not working correct. I tried a lot and nothing helped. Any advice would be great!

**Here the captured packet:**

```
POST /WAZZUUPWS/rest/service/user/integrate HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.115:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: de;q=1, en;q=0.9, fr;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5
User-Agent: WAZZUUP!/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 6.1.4; Scale/2.00)
```

Comment: `requestDescriptor` doesn't appear to be linked to the `UserDTO` class. Is that a typo?

Comment: dude i just saw that. I'll check that when i m home. I  hope thats the problem! Write a answer that i can give credits if its true!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might just be a typo in your question but `requestDescriptor` doesn't appear to be linked to the UserDTO class.

Comment: had a few problems after thetypo bu t it rreally was the typo! ty very much

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not have an understanding of Core Data objects yet. Objects that are persisted using Core Data are subclasses of NSManagedObject and have to be created differently. Read further on this link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html

As for the current problem, you have to use this instead:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserDTO" inManagedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

UserDTO *user = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

However, if UserDTO is a subclass of NSObject, that would need to change to NSManagedObject.

My workflow is something like this - create Core Data model and use mogenerator to automatically generate the NSManagedObject class definitions. Read more about it here:http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/

Comment: My Qeustion has nothing todo with Coredata, sry.